Fluent UI Vertical Bar Chart refuses to show x-axis values without a separator
I'm populating a bar chart with my data and no matter what I do, I can't get the x-axis values to drop the separators. The x-axis values are supposed to be years and I can't figure out where and how to format the date in a way that will produce the '2025' result and not '2 025'.

I map through a JSON and populate the x-values with new Date(string value).getFullYear() as I only want the x-axis values to be years. If I get the date object without getting the year, I end up with '2025-01-01' which I don't want.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
